# React Bootstrap Typeahead children onclick

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have been using a Premade React-Bootstrap Typeahead search-bar found [here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead)

I am having trouble accessing the child elements from the dropdown. I want to be able to have an Onclick function for the dropdown items, but it doesn't seem like I have access to the children.

Below is the code I have currently, where I use typeahead

```
<div className="search-bar">
  <Typeahead
    id="sample"
    options= {cities.map((city) => (city))}
    labelKey="name"
    placeholder="Enter a city"
  />
</div>
```

How do I get an onclick for these element cities listed?

Comment: https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/HEAD/docs/Props.md
go through this link, you will get all the props and events details

Comment: https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize menu rendering and behavior by using the [`renderMenu`](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Rendering.md#rendermenuresults-arrayobjectstring-menuprops-object) prop:

```
<Typeahead
  options={options}
  renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => (
    <Menu {...menuProps}>
      {results.map((result, index) => (
        <MenuItem
          onClick={() => console.log('click!')}
          option={result}
          position={index}>
          {result.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  )}
/>
```

With the menu items exposed, you're free to add your own `onClick` handler to each item. Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-flower-6tlh1).

Comment: Thanks so much Eric! Thank you for creating the component as well!

Comment: Is it possible to do this while still maintaining the pagination functionality? When I use renderMenu, the pagination option at the bottom no longer works.

Comment: @heather: Yes it should work just fine without any additional effort. Note that `maxResults` defaults to `100`, so in the linked example above with a max of 50 results, you'll never see the pagination item. If you change it to a smaller number, it'll show up: https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-custom-menu-rendering-ynljk

Comment: Actually it's not working example by the link

Comment: how do you make it work with `newSelectionPrefix`?